# Getting an easily readable function name from a function object in python

Tags: python, function, reflection, naming

Trying to get a function name in Python, I would like to achieve something like this:

```
def my_function():
    do_something...

def get_func_name(function):
    return magic(function)

>>> print get_func_name(my_function)
>>> my_function
```

How should this be done?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has a magical attribute `__name__`.

```
def get_func_name(function):
    return function.__name__
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def my_function():
    pass

def get_func_name(function):
    try:
        # Python2
        return function.func_name
    except AttributeError:
        # Python3
        return function.__name__

print(get_func_name(my_function))
```